# Vega Lite font availability

Tags: vega-lite

I was wondering if there is a list of supported fonts used by Vega Lite? I didn't manage to find in the docs but maybe missed in.

Specifically I am trying to use museo sans 300, which works fine in my D3.js code, but doesn't seem to be recognised in Vega Lite.

Is there a way to link to custom font files?

Comment: Answer to Q3 in this link shows how to configure fonts in Vega-Lite
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45326497/vega-lite-bar-chart-space-between-bars.

Font related configurations are available in most configurations like ```axis``` (label and title), ```text``` mark etc. Here are some references in the documents.
https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/axis.html#labels
https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/text.html#labels

Comment: Thank you ! In the end it turned out to be because of the order of loading things onto the webpage, now resolved. Thanks for input.

Answer (score 1):

The way I get custom fonts for Vega Lite charts in my website is simply via CSS!

**First**: Define a font in your CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: MyFont;
    src: url(fonts/somefont.ttf);
}
```

**Second**: Refer to the font name in your Vega Lite configs

```
axis : {
titleFont: "MyFont"
}
```

Hope this helps, this is not directly related to your goal from question but still gives you ability to do custom fonts inside the chart.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I have tried this in a google cloud app but it's not working. It works for any text I write on the html, but not for the text on the chart. I wonder if you could share additional details.